# svn status after revert reports ignored files

Tags: svn, working-copy

I changed a lot of source-code files using a shell-script and reverted the changes with the command `svn revert -R .`. Every change had been undone correctly, but now I'm wondering why `svn status` reports ignored files:

```
$> svn status
!    .
!    src
!    src/lib
!    src/lib/common
!    src/lib/common/parser
!    src/lib/common/parser/xml
```

This is the entire output! I have much more folders, but I cannot tell you why only those appear here. None of the upper folders are added to svn:ignore property!

Does anybody know what happened?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn help status` documents the '!' as:

```
 '!' item is missing (removed by non-svn command) or incomplete
```

Which explains what happened: Some files were added to subversion and after that deleted. The 'ignored' setting only applies to files that were never added (or "unversioned files").

The 'incomplete' status is another possible reason for this status. In this case a previous update operation was canceled (or failed).

In both cases you can resolve this problem by simply running 'svn update' (again).

Comment: Yes, after second update it had been solved. I should have checked first the help and not the web. I had a look at this reference http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html (first result with google) describes "!" as ignore =/

Comment: Note that this book describes capital i as ignore and ! as I did above, but the font makes it hard to spot the difference.